# Batch: Grab first letter of a string

Tags: batch-file

Currently testing a few things and wandered if it was possible to grab the first letter of a string and assign it to a variable?

Some context/example:

```
set USRDIR1==\\SERVER\Users\%username%
if not exist %USRDIR1% mdkir %USRDIR1%

rem // grab first letter from %username% and assign to %firstletter% //

set USDIR2==\\SERVER\Users\%firstletter%\%Username%
if not exist %USRDIR2% mkdir %USRDIR2%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set USRDIR1==\\SERVER\Users\%username%
if not exist %USRDIR1% mdkir %USRDIR1%

rem // grab first letter from %username% and assign to %firstletter% //
set firstletter=%username:~0,1%

set USDIR2==\\SERVER\Users\%firstletter%\%Username%
if not exist %USRDIR2% mkdir %USRDIR2%
```

[Check variable substring syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)