# Is there a set /p wildcard entry?

Tags: batch-file, variables, if-statement, wildcard

I'm sure there is a way but my google game is not that strong.  Is there a way to get a wildcard entry for set /p?  In my example I will use * to show where I would like the wildcard.

```
set /p exam="enter exam number "
if %exam%=6* goto 1
if %exam%=2* goto 2
```

So if the exam starts with 6 it will go to :1 same with it starting with 2.
Hopefully I explained this well enough.

Comment: Is this in P? This doesn't look like it's in P.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch: Grab first letter of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800162/batch-grab-first-letter-of-a-string)

Comment: @Will This is not P, it is a batch file